# Android app crashes in release mode for gms.vision api

Tags: java, android, gradle, 64-bit

I have used the gms.vision api for barcode scanning in my application. I upgraded my studio, gradle to create the aab file. I started to face the crash issue only in release mode with the below log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected number of IObjectWrapper declared fields: 0
    at vyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@19275046@19.2.75 (120400-269183835):9)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.client.DynamiteNativeBarcodeDetectorCreator.newBarcodeDetector(:com.google.android.gms@19275046@19.2.75 (120400-269183835):1)
    at awhf.a(:com.google.android.gms@19275046@19.2.75 (120400-269183835):3)
    at cqq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@19275046@19.2.75 (120400-269183835):3)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.c$a$a.a(Unknown Source:40)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.d$a.b(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.d$a.a(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.d.b(Unknown Source:11)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.d.<init>(Unknown Source:17)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.a$b.a(Unknown Source:6)
```

I have added the vision library under dependency as follows:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:"8.3.0"
```

Without upgrading the vision api version, is there a way to fix this crash issue?

Comment: try running the app in release mode with `minifyEnabled false`and `shrinkResources false` and check if this still crashes for you?

Comment: If you are using Instant Run, then disable Instant Run and make a released version and try it.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: did you use the android-vision-master from github?

Comment: i am using proguard. making minifyEnabled to false doesn't affect app security ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line in gradle.properties file has resolved the crash issue:

```
android.enableR8=false
```